# How to create dotted line in a DXF file?

Tags: autocad, dxf

I want to generate a dotted line in my DXF file but I don't know the code and the value which I should use to. I have gone through Autocad reference but unable to find what I am looking for. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Desire Line Example :

-------------- Or .............

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? You know how to create a line? A dxf file contains a section called `TABLES` with line types. The line entities are in the simple case located in the `ENTITIES` section. For each `LINE` entity you can refer to a line type in the `TABLES` section using group code 6. The easiest way is to create a dashed/dotted line in Autocad and look in the created `DXF` file once you have a basic understanding of the `DXF` format.

Comment: Yes, I am creating a DXF library and want to generate a dotted line in it. I have created a simple line. Yes I am getting idea form it. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

You are needing to set the LTYPE property of the line object you have created, Group Code 6. You will need to check to see what styles are available, and perhaps define your own style.

[Here](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/common_group_codes_for_entities_dxf_06.htm#XREF_22164_DXF_06) is a resource for you.